# mp4 movie does not play with the flowplayer iPad plugin

Tags: video-streaming, mp4, flowplayer

I am trying to run an mp4 movie using the iPad plugin of flowplayer. Unfortunately all I get is an empty player with a strike through player button. I could not find any information what that means?

First thing I tried was putting the absolute path to the movie in the href attribute but the movie didn't work on localhost.

When I put the absolute path to an example movie hosted on stream.flowplayer.org it worked. But the same movie didn't work on localhost. That brought me to the conclusion that some special configuration for the apache server is necessary to let the video run.

Could you please help? Here is my code:

```
<a href="movie.mp4" id="flash" style="display:block;width:640px;height:360px;"></a>
    <script>
      $f("flash", "flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.10.swf", {
        clip:  {
          autoPlay: true,
          autoBuffering: true
        }
      }).ipad();
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="movie.mp4" id="flash" style="display:block;width:640px;height:360px;"></a>

<script>
  $f("flash", "flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.10.swf", {
    clip:  {
      url:"mp4:movie",    // change this
      autoPlay: true,
      autoBuffering: true
    }
  }).ipad();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're hosting on Apache, here is how to use .htaccess files to configure a valid MP4 mime-type on your local server: http://www.htaccess-guide.com/adding-mime-types/

If this is hosted on a Windows server. You probably need to add the MP4 mime-type to IIS:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1470612.aspx/1

Comment: If it works on Windows or Mac it's not a missing mime-type.  If you can switch to another video player, try [JW Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/).  I have worked a lot with FlowPlayer and jwPlayer.  I have had better luck with jwPlayer  across all platforms.

Comment: @barsh He said a video hosted ELSEWHERE (stream.flowplayer.org) worked, and localhost failed. While I did just notice he mentions his local machine is running Apache I don't see where he mentions anything about it working on Windows or Mac *except* when accessing the video when it's hosted on Flowplayer.org. So I've updated my answer to include adjusting mime types for Apache.

Comment: I added "AddType video/mp4 mp4" both to my .htaccess file and httpd.conf but to no avail. Though it should be server configuration issue for I tested some videos that work when I link them from one of the flowplayer servers but not from localhost or my production server. I should mention that the videos play in the desktop web browser but not from within the iOS simulator or devie.

Answer (score -1):

```
<a id="audio<?=$musicData['audio_id']?>" href="<?=$file?>" class="player" style="display:block;width:100%;height:350px;"></a>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
                    $f("audio<?=$musicData['audio_id']?>", "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf", {
                        clip: {
                                autoPlay : false,
                                coverImage: { url: "<?=APPLICATION_URL?>images/icons/images/url.gif"
                                    }
                            }
                    }).ipad();
                       // $f("audio<?=$musicData['audio_id']?>", "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf").ipad();
</script>
```